# Is it possible to add just a column to a table? (oracle sql)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

```
  Person Name       Birthday        City   
      Mary          December       New York
      John           March          Seatle
      Peter         November       Los Angeles
```

Assuming all people are male...

how can i add a new column Gender with value M, like the example below?
Is it possible?

```
  Person Name       Birthday        City         Gender
      Mary          December       New York        M
      John           March          Seatle         M
      Peter         November       Los Angeles     M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```
alter table t add gender varchar2(1) default 'M'
```

EDIT:

If you just want to return a column in a `SELECT`, you can do:

```
select t.*, 'M' as gender
from t;
```

However, you cannot modify the table from a `SELECT`.

Comment: I was not specific in the question above. How can i do that command in a SELECT statement like: ALTER TABLE (SELECT ... ) ADD gender VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'M'

Comment: @AndreProenza what is your syntax meant to do? Perhaps there is some other way to do it. `alter table` must be followed by a table name.